# How to join multiple nodes to one node in iOS scene

Tags: ios, scenekit

As we can see in below pic there all multiple nodes in the scene graph. The requirement is I want to add these nodes in one node as shown in image2. So In scene graph, I will have one node(chair) which will contain multiple nodes

[image]

```
                      Image1
```

[image]

```
                    Image2
```

Answer (score 6):

You create a parent node and then add all your nodes as children.

i.e.:

```
var nodes: [SCNNode] = getMyNodes()

var parentNode = SCNNode()
parentNode.name = "chair"

for node in nodes {
    parentNode.addChildNodes(node)
}
```

When you apply an update to a node, the update is also pushed down to the children, for example:

```
parentNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0.5, 1.2)
```

will apply the same translation transformation to all the children attached to `parentNode`.

You can access a specific child using:

```
parentNode.childNode(withName: nameOfChildNode, recursively: true)
```

and get the parent of any child using:

```
myChildNode.parent
```

EDIT:

If you are importing from a scene file, you can still easily access your nodes programmatically:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "myScene.scn")

func getMyNodes() -> [SCNNode] {
    var nodes: [SCNNode] = [SCNNode]()
    for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
        nodes.append(node)
    }
    return nodes
}
```

which, incidentally, means that you can ignore most of the above and use `myScene.rootNode` as the `parent` node.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions would be :

- Statically : Create a new .scn file in which you drag & drop every node you're trying to group
- Dynamically : Create a new SCNNode. For each node you're trying to group, use the .addChildNode method

I used the second one a couple of times to build dynamical scenes using  ARKit. Worked like a charm.

Basically, I added all the childs of my .dae file to a SCNNode :

```
var node = SCNNode()
let scene = SCNScene(named: "myScene.dae")
var nodeArray = scene.rootNode.childNodes

for childNode in nodeArray {
  node.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
}
```

You should give it a try with your files, using the same .addChildNode method :)

Comment: Could you please share the code for dynamically approach

Answer (score 0):

in case, if somebody is looking for a solution like this yellow-black stick

```
class VirtualObject: SCNNode {

    enum Style {
        case anchor
        case fence
    }

    let style: Style
    var value: String?

    init(_ style: Style) {
        self.style = style
        super.init()

        switch style {
        case .anchor:
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.magenta
            material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased

            let object = SCNCone(topRadius: 0.02, bottomRadius: 0, height: 0.1)  // SCNSphere(radius: 0.02)
            object.materials = [material]

            self.geometry = object

        case .fence:
            for index in 0 ... 6 {
                let material = SCNMaterial()
                material.diffuse.contents = index % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.yellow : UIColor.black
                material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased

                let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNCylinder(radius: 0.01, height: 0.05))
                node.geometry?.materials = [material]
                node.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0.05 * Float(index), 0)
                addChildNode(node)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Yellow-black stivk in AR]