# Apply translation to root node does not work as expected for the second time onwards

Tags: swift, arkit, scnnode, apple-vision

This is a continuation project from my previous question.
[How to move multiple nodes in ARSCNView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417412/how-to-move-multiple-nodes-in-arscnview)

The previous program was a prototype. The purpose of this function is to move the AR object which is added by hand tracking using hand tracking by the Vision framework (not UI hand gesture recognizer). A large part of the app is based on ARPaint created by kkoronuei. https://github.com/kkorouei/ARPaint

The code I have posted happens inside `func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {`. Basically the app has 2 modes. `drawMode` is where the anchors are added, otherwise it is to move the drawing using hand gesture. Two modes cannot happen at the same time, so the app is either in `drawMode` or not in it. My current logic is to group all the existing node to a new node called `motherNode` and apply the translation matrix to it. `indexTip2` refers to the finger `VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint` of the index finger tip from the vision framework. 'distance' refers the distance to the camera calculated by the Lidar sensor. These 2 variables work without issues. From these 2 variables I can create the translation Matrix and move the entire scene to the current finger position (for now I will not worry which node is being moved, as long everything is shifted in the right direction).

This works for the first time. However, when it is called again, this `motherNode` already exists so to avoid creating the same node over and over again, I have added an if loop to skip the creation method. The current problem is when I reuse the commented out lines, the object does not move to the finger position anymore. It either fades out of sight very quickly or it does not move at all. I might have made a mistake using swift options but I am not sure. Surely the translation to the root node can be applied multiple times right? Any thought is much appreciated.

```
            if (!drawMode.isOn){
                
                var parentNode: SCNNode?
                var nodes: [SCNNode] = getMyNodes()
                parentNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "motherNode", recursively: true)

                if parentNode != nil {
//                    guard let touchPositionInFrontOfCamera = getPosition(ofPoint: indexTip2, atDistanceFromCamera: self.distance, inView: self.sceneView) else { return }
//                    print(touchPositionInFrontOfCamera)
//                    let translationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Translate(parentNode!.worldTransform,
//                    touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.x,
//                     touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.y,
//                     touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.z)
//                    parentNode!.transform = translationMatrix
                    return
                }
                parentNode = SCNNode()
                parentNode!.name = "motherNode"
                for node in nodes {
                    parentNode!.addChildNode(node)
                }
                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(parentNode!)
                guard let touchPositionInFrontOfCamera = getPosition(ofPoint: indexTip2, atDistanceFromCamera: self.distance, inView: self.sceneView) else { return }
                let translationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Translate(parentNode!.worldTransform,
                touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.x,
                 touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.y,
                 touchPositionInFrontOfCamera.z)
                parentNode!.transform = translationMatrix
                return
            }
```

I have added a few print lines to see what is going on. The following prints the `translationMatrix` when it is initialized. Then prints `touchPositionInFrontOfCamera` and 'translationMatrix' inside the if loop.

```
______
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 0.5359205, m42: 0.18874621, m43: -1.810905, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.58134866, y: -0.099451624, z: -1.8089545)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 1.1172692, m42: 0.08929459, m43: -3.6198595, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5735985, y: 0.01310969, z: -1.8194867)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 1.6908677, m42: 0.10240428, m43: -5.4393463, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5767575, y: -0.01947598, z: -1.8248432)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 2.267625, m42: 0.0829283, m43: -7.2641897, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.53923947, y: 0.012032239, z: -1.8421669)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 2.8068645, m42: 0.09496054, m43: -9.106357, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5817139, y: -0.086378224, z: -1.8321315)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 3.3885784, m42: 0.008582316, m43: -10.938488, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5687888, y: -0.064390875, z: -1.8420491)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 3.9573672, m42: -0.05580856, m43: -12.780537, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5444935, y: -0.063903295, z: -1.855654)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 4.5018606, m42: -0.11971185, m43: -14.63619, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.5435701, y: -0.06915884, z: -1.8613077)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 5.0454307, m42: -0.1888707, m43: -16.497498, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.3528172, y: -0.0486469, z: -1.9168768)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 5.3982477, m42: -0.2375176, m43: -18.414375, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.34087926, y: -0.053323507, z: -1.9242713)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 5.739127, m42: -0.2908411, m43: -20.338646, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.58009064, y: -0.22830658, z: -1.8522431)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 6.3192177, m42: -0.5191477, m43: -22.19089, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.42730594, y: -0.17960595, z: -1.9075701)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 6.746524, m42: -0.69875365, m43: -24.09846, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.47545266, y: -0.20432584, z: -1.8975433)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 7.2219763, m42: -0.9030795, m43: -25.996002, m44: 1.0)
SCNVector3(x: 0.4368087, y: -0.15196265, z: -1.9180105)
SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.0, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 7.658785, m42: -1.0550421, m43: -27.914013, m44: 1.0)
```

As you can see the `translationMatrix` will eventually grow so huge it becomes impossible to see. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, `worldTransform` keeps the record of transformation applied to the node up to date.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407970-worldtransform
Therefore it will always update itself with previous values. So the solution is do not use `worldTransform` and use `pivot` instead.